# How do I create a count function to count the amount of numbers in a sequence from another function?

Tags: c++

I'm working on a school assignment, and can't figure out how to create a function to count how many numbers are printed in a sequence. I had it working before(shown below) but the count function needs to be it's own:

*7. Write a contract, then an implementation, of a function that takes an integer n and returns the length of the hailstone sequence starting at n. This function must not write (print) anything.*

*Modify your main function to so that it shows both the hailstone sequence and the length of the hailstone sequence starting at n.*

I'm still rather new to C++, and I'm still learning how to do most of this. Sorry if it's a dumb thing to ask help with.

```
// This program takes a user defined number 'n'
// and runs it through a function that returns 
// the number that follows 'n' in hailstone sequence.
// Since there is no number that follows 1 in the sequence,
// this fuction requires its parameter 'n' to be greater
// than 1. 

/*
  What number shall I start with?  7
  The hailstone sequence starting at 7 is:
  7 22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1
  The length of the sequence is 17.
  The largest number in the sequence is 52.
  The longest hailstone sequence starting with a number up to 7 has length 17
  The longest hailstone sequence starting with a number up to 7 begins with 7
*/

#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdio>
using namespace std;

void hailstoneSequence(int n);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{ 

    int n;

    printf("What number shall I start with? ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("The hailtone sequence starting at %d is: \n", n);

    hailstoneSequence(n);

return 0;
}

// In hailstoneSequence, while 'n' is not equal to 1 
// the function will calculate whether 'n' is even 
// to computer n/2, otherwise it will compute 3n + 1 if 'n' is odd. 

void hailstoneSequence(int n)
{   

// hailLength will keep track of how many
// numbers are produced in the sequence. 

    int hailLength = 1;

    printf("%i", n);
    printf(" ");



    while(n != 1)
    {
        if(n % 2 == 0)
        {
            n /= 2;
            printf("%i", n);
            printf(" ");
        }
        else
        {
            n = (3 * n) + 1;
            printf("%i", n);
            printf(" ");
        }
        hailLength++;

    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("The length of the sequence is %i.", hailLength);
    printf("\n");
}
```

This is the other function I was trying to go with to count the amount of times the hailstoneSequence was used.

```
int hailstoneLength(int hailLength)
{
  hailLength++;
  return hailLength;
}
```

This is part of my main function when tryign to work with the count function:

```
 int main(int argc, char** argv)
 { 
   int n;
   int hailLength = 0;
```

And this is the hailstoneSequence function after:

```
while(n != 1)
{
    if(n % 2 == 0)
    {
        n /= 2;
        printf("%i", n);
        printf(" ");
    }
    else
    {
        n = (3 * n) + 1;
        printf("%i", n);
        printf(" ");
    }
    hailstoneLength(hailLength);
    //hailLength++;
}
```

I'm sure I'm breaking it more now. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong, or help me understand how to get the function to count? I'm still trying to google how to call functions in functions and stuff to try those methods.

Would it be easier to use if statements without the while loop?
I can't use recursions either for this assignment.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you only need to create _another_ function that produces the size of the Hailstone sequence. The two functions will look similar, but one prints output and the other counts iterations.

Comment: Thanks, how do I make it known that I want the function to count how many iterations of the loop it did? I'm not understanding it tht well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your hailstoneSequence function as follows and remove the declaration of hailLength and nbl from `main()`
`int n;
  int hailLength = 1;
while(n != 1)
{
    if(n % 2 == 0)
    {
        n /= 2;
        printf("%i", n);
        printf(" ");
    }
    else
    {
        n = (3 * n) + 1;
        printf("%i", n);
        printf(" ");
    }
    hailLength=hailstoneLength(hailLength); //You should store the returned value somewhere
    //hailLength++;
}
printf("\n");
    printf("The length of the sequence is %i.", hailLength);
    printf("\n");`

Comment: I'm understanding this a bit better, so I need to put main() in the hailtoneSequence in order for it to send data to main? I should also remove hailLength from main, but what is nbl referring to?

Comment: As for the returned value, I remember that now. I was thinking I should ask for help and take a short break so I can focus better on this.

Comment: I tried your method and am coming with compiling errors for hailstoneLength = hailstoneLength(hailLength);